# What is causing a price and stock reindex?

Tags: magento-1.8, reindex

Every 5 minutes the price and stock is getting reindexed. The unix cron is running every 5 minutes but I have disabled that to test and it still happens.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to find out what is causing the reindex?

Comment: Are you running Commerce (Enterprise) or Open Source (Community) edition? I'd also try using `crontab -l` to view the crontabs of both your root and web user since both can hold separate cronstabs.

Comment: @MattAntleyit's It's CE. I'll check the crontabs for all users. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Any luck with this? Are you still having an issue?

Comment: Yes, still having the issue. We're on shared hosting so I can't see root crontab. I need to talk to the hosts to see if there are any running.